# how to save selected div background color inside localstorage?

Tags: javascript, css

im sorry if my Question duplicated but i need help
im trying to save the selected color to localstorage and keep the last selected color after reload the page.  i mean to get last saved color inside localstorage 
  and kep the box with last selected color  after reload  the page 
any idea?

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");
const colorInput = document.querySelector("input");
const currentColorSpan = document.querySelector("#currentColorSpan");

colorInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
  box.style.backgroundColor = colorInput.value;
  currentColorSpan.textContent = colorInput.value;
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 600px;
  height: 360px;
  border: solid 1px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">color slected not saved yet inside localstorag</div>
<label>click picker to choose color</label>
<input type="color" value="#ffffff"/>
<p>current color: <span id="currentColorSpan"></span></p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate [Keep CSS from refreshing on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441624/keep-css-from-refreshing-on-page-reload)

Comment: no sir its far way from answer..i need to save selected color from picker and bring it back after reload watch this example http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/demo/html5-js/localstorage.html but this example for body background ...i need to set background for div or clas