# CSS Add Class active to block after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="side-button"> 
   <a href="/first"> First Option <a>
</div>
  <div class="side-button"> 
   <a href="/second"> Second Option <a>
</div>
```

When user click on one of the blocks, I want it to become active, so that I can highlight it with another color.

In my jQuery I'm trying to add class `active` on the clicked block:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $(".side-button").bind('click', function () {
      $(".side-button").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

It works while next page is loading. After redirect, it doesn't remember `active` class.

How can I add class `active` so it will remember that on the loaded page?

Comment: Use local storage to remember the state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep CSS from refreshing on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441624/keep-css-from-refreshing-on-page-reload)

Comment: `sessionStorage` would probably be more appropriate here

Comment: @Shree Thank you! Works great!

Answer (score 2):

for remember something on redirect/page load, we can use local storage/session storage

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
        var retrievedClassName = localStorage.getItem('activeClass');
        if(retrievedClassName == "active"){
             //add active class to your element
        }
        $(".side-button").bind('click', function () {
          $(".side-button").removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
          localStorage.setItem('activeClass', "active");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Your script help to remeber that ```.side-button``` was clicked. But i have like 8 blocks with the same class ```.side-button```. So on this step: ```//add active class to your element``` i can't just add active class, since it will be applied to all 8 blocks. I need also somehow to remember which of ```.side-button``` was clicked exactly.

Comment: for that, you need to have a unique IDs for the 8 blocks. by that, you can remember which side button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`Window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) OR [`Window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). But before proceeding I will request you to look into: [`HTML5 Local storage vs. Session storage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/html5-local-storage-vs-session-storage)

**Session storage:**

You can use [`Window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to set the elements `href` attribute and `class` inside the click event. Then get those from [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) on page load to set on the element:

```
// Get
var status = sessionStorage.getItem("status");
var elHref = sessionStorage.getItem("elementsHref")
$("a[href$='"+elHref+"']").addClass(status);

$(document).ready(function($){
  $("a").bind('click', function () {
    // Set
    sessionStorage.setItem("status", "active");
    sessionStorage.setItem("elementsHref", $(this).attr("href"))
    $("a").removeClass(sessionStorage.getItem("status"));
    $(this).addClass(sessionStorage.getItem("status"));
  });
});
```

**Local storage:**

You can achieve the same by using [`Window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) like the following:

```
// Get
var status = localStorage.getItem("status");
var elHref = localStorage.getItem("elementsHref")
$("a[href$='"+elHref+"']").addClass(status);

$(document).ready(function($){
  $("a").bind('click', function () {
    // Set
    localStorage.setItem("status", "active");
    localStorage.setItem("elementsHref", $(this).attr("href"))
    $("a").removeClass(localStorage.getItem("status"));
    $(this).addClass(localStorage.getItem("status"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){
    $(".block").on('click', function () {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```