# Run same button function after refresh - jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a simple code which changes background color through jquery. but after refresh the color goes back to default and how I could use the same function after reload. I'm using wordpress, can also use php language.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dark").click(function() {
    $("#body-tech").css("background-color", "black");
    $("#body-tech h1").css("color", "white");
    $("#body-tech .ct-text-block").css("color", "white");
    $("#dark").css("display", "none");
    $("#light").css("display", "")
  })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#light").click(function() {
    $("#body-tech").css("background-color", "white");
    $("#body-tech h1").css("color", "black");
    $("#body-tech .ct-text-block").css("color", "black");
    $("#light").css("display", "none");
    $("#dark").css("display", "")
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="dark">darkmode</button>
<button id="light" style="display:none;">lightmode</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by - "but after refresh"?

Comment: You need to persist the state of the user. Depending on the framework you can either use cookies or application storage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep CSS from refreshing on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441624/keep-css-from-refreshing-on-page-reload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `localStorage`

```js
let bgColor = localStorage.getItem("bgcolor");

document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;

function themeFunc(e){
    localStorage.setItem("bgcolor", e.value);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}
```

```html
<button id="dark" value="black" onclick="themeFunc(this)">Dark</button>
<button id="light" value="white" onclick="themeFunc(this)">Light</button>
```